# function to find words that starts and ends with the same letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to make a function that finds the words that starts - however me code leads to an error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any idea why?

```
list1 = ['ala', 'ma', 'piegi', 'kajak']

def first_last(strings):
    lista = []
    for word in strings:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            lista += 1
    return lista

print(first_last(list1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning a list comprehension that includes the items after checking that condition, will be enough:

```
def first_last(list1):
    return [word for word in list1 if word[0] == word[-1]]
```

You were getting that error because you were attempting to concatenate the list `lista` with an integer. You were looking for `append()` method in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add one to an empty list. You can add one to another number.

```
list1 = ['ala', 'ma', 'piegi', 'kajak']

def first_last(strings):
    lista = []
    for word in strings:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            lista.append(word)
    return lista

print(first_last(list1))
```

The code above adds the word itself to your list.